# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@ID = @@IDENTITY'

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I have given valuable advise from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622011/unable-to-retrieve-microsoft-access-autonumber-values)

But as subject title says I am receiving error in the btnLogin method, related to my previous question but really the same problem, I think? I say this because I was not getting error from my pervious question.  Thanks in advance if anyone can help me here.

access 2003
VS 2010 c#

This is my btnLogin method

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES (@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime)";
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY"; 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedInDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedInTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();
```

This is my btnLogOut method.

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

       cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE [LoginLogTable] SET [LoggedOutDate] = ?, [LoggedOutTime] = ? WHERE ID = @ID";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedOutDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedOutTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The purpose of the code the code is record the date and time when user logs in and the date and time when the user logs out.

**Update 2**
I have tried this as well...

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES (@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime)" +  "SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY";
```

Then I am receiving error of...

> Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.

**Update 3**

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES 
(@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime)";   "SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY";
```

I have placed a ; and I am getting error of...

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Looking at other solutions provided my other members

**Update 4**

I think some of the advise here may only work for SQL Server. I am using MS Access 2003.

**Update 5**

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES 
(@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime);  SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY";
```

receiving error...

> Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: But what are you trying to do with that second statement? You don't read back that value `(@ID)` anywhere.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running this against? Why do you have ms-access in your tags?

Comment: I am using MS ACCESS - I thought perhaps someone with SQL Server knowledge maybe able to help me, another words widening the tags to reach further a field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you may have an error in your code.  You set the Text of the cmd to the first line, then completely replace it with the second one:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES (@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime)";
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY";
```

So you are effectively only executing:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY";
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply if you don't mind could you have a look at my update?

Comment: @bucketblast Then put a `;` at the end of your first statement. Hint: after the `@LoggedInTime)`.

Comment: @bucketblast DaveShaw meant to include it in your SQL statement: `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES (@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime); SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY"`

Comment: @MartinParkin - Receiving error - Characters found after end of SQL statement. I will update at the top

Comment: @bucketblast If you are using MS Access you need to carry out the `INSERT` and the `SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY` statement as two separate commands, one after the other.  You cannot execute them in the same statement against MS Access.  The `@@IDENTITY` will be preserved across the connection object so you won't lose it.

Comment: @MartinParkin - Is that not what I was doing originally. I am confused from your original answer? Could advise or show how it could be done, pls?

Comment: @bucketblast You were not doing this originally, as I said in my answer, you were overwriting the original statement with another.  You were not executing both, only the second one.  You must first execute the `INSERT` (by running `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`) then execute the `SELECT`.  Do not close the connection in between or you will lose the `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: @MartinParkin - It seems your solution has been solved. As I used to say when I was teen, wicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In first login method, you override the commandtext, by setting it twice:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES (@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime)";
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY";
```

In 'update 2', you are concatting the SELECT-statement right after the INSERT-statement, resulting in the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES (@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime)SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY
```

You must set an ';' at the end of the INSERT-statement, before the 'SELECT'.

And btw. use SCOPE_IDENTITY(), instead of @@IDENTITY, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx and [SQL: How to get the id of values I just INSERTed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651/sql-how-to-get-the-id-of-values-i-just-inserted)

Also, here is an similar question, showing the correct way to execute the command:
[How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Comment: Oh, i missed the Access part. No, i dont think it does :-)

Comment: It doesn't matter. I am going back to original plan. That is when user logs out, date and time will be logged to new id (autonumber). It seems MS-Access and C# is OK for basics only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of fetching the user id, you have to combine both the statments in to a single batch

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginLogTable (UserName, LoggedInDate, LoggedInTime) VALUES (@UserName, @LoggedInDate, @LoggedInTime) SELECT @@IDENTITY";
```

Comment: TrustyCoder - I done @LoggedInTime); SELECT but getting error