# C# Must declare the scalar variable "@SomeThing" in insert query

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on .net c# , I want to insert some data into a table.

I am write query in Visual Studio and not using stored procedure(s).

This is my query

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Device_Events (Device_ID, Event_ID, Occurrence_Time, Recovery_Time) values (@Device_ID , @Event_ID, @Occurrence_Time, @Recovery_Time)", con);
```

And this is my C# code for passing values in it

```
// For Events
string formatString = "yyMMddHHmmss";
DateTime Occurrence_Time, Recovery_Time;
string strOccurrence = Meter_data.Substring(161, 12);
string strRecovery = Meter_data.Substring(173, 12);

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_ID", device_Id);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event_ID", event_Id);

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time))
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time))
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Occurrence_Time;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Recovery_Time;
    }
}

int Device_Events_rows_executed = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Rows Executed: '{0}'", Device_Events_rows_executed);
```

It doesn't goes into the `if` part and i am getting an exception named `Must declare the scalar variable "@Occurrence_Time"`

Also i have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20330905/6856823) but unable to find any help

**Updated Code**

After a suggestion I have added following piece of code

```
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Device_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = device_Id;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Event_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = event_Id;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;

            string formatString = "yyMMddHHmmss";
            DateTime Occurrence_Time, Recovery_Time;
            string strOccurrence = Meter_data.Substring(161, 12);
            string strRecovery = Meter_data.Substring(173, 12);

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time))
            {
                cmd2.Parameters["@Occurrence_Time"].Value = Occurrence_Time;
            }
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time))
            {
                cmd2.Parameters["@Recovery_Time"].Value = Recovery_Time;
            }
```

Although it's not showing me and error or exception but still it doesn't gets into the both `if` conditions

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You need to always provide values for all query parameters. Just because some data started in the wrong format does not change this.

Comment: Is this actual code? You are using `AddWithValue` but passing arguments as if you are trying to use `Add` - I would suggest [not using `AddWithValue` at all](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: What is type of your column Occurrence_Time?

Comment: And what is the exact value of variable "Occurrence_Time"?

Comment: @SirajHussain the type is  `datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need to declare all parameters but you can pass a `null`or default value in case of missing date:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time))
{               
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Occurrence_Time;                
}
else 
{
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = null;
}
```

Comment: Actually i'am getting data from meter and it's sending me event(s) data, also i get accurate device ID for particular event but in all cases it doesn't go inside if part

Comment: so obviously the sub-string within `strOccurrence` doesn't match `yyMMddHHmmss` otherwise `DateTime.TryParseExact` would return `true`

Comment: At first it was matching, i don't know what had happened

Comment: @GarethD i have also tried with `Add` but still the result is same

Comment: @faisal1208 debug your code and take a look at the content of `strOccurrence `

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated, because of your conditional flows, there are code paths where you will try and execute `cmd2` without adding the parameters to the command.

The parameters have to be added to the command, even if they don't have a value. I'd suggest setting up all the parameters at the start (using `Add()` rather than `AddWithValue()`):

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Device_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = device_Id;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Event_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = event_Id;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Then later on, if your strings parse correctly as dates, update the value of the parameter:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time))
{
    cmd2.Parameters["@Occurrence_Time"].Value = Occurrence_Time;
}
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time))
{
    cmd2.Parameters["@Recovery_Time"].Value = Recovery_Time;
}
```

**EDIT**

You seem very confident that the data will always be correct, so you may as well just use `ParseExact` instead of `TryParseExact`:

```
var occuranceDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Meter_data.Substring(161, 12), "yyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var recoveryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Meter_data.Substring(173, 12), "yyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Device_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = device_Id;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Event_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = event_Id;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = occuranceDate'
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = recoveryDate;

int Device_Events_rows_executed = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Rows Executed: '{0}'", Device_Events_rows_executed);
```

Comment: Ok, i'll add this piece of code but before it i want to tell you that i have total of  **400**  size string in which 160 is filled up and the remaining is divided into 25 25 pieces of chunks and in 25 chunk 12 is for Occurrence and 12 is for Recover and remaining 1 is for comma, so that's why i have added `string strOccurrence = Meter_data.Substring(161, 12);
            string strRecovery = Meter_data.Substring(173, 12);`

Comment: So do you want to throw an exception if either date is not in a valid format? Have you tried debugging your code to see what the value of the string is that is failing to be converted?

Comment: I want to insert the Occurrence Time and Recovery Time with correct format

Comment: Dates do not have a format. What I am asking is, if your meter_Data is invalid, e.g. if `Meter_data.Substring(173, 12)`  gave you a result of `ThisIsNotADate`, what should happen?

Comment: It is giving me correct date time as `161025120830` but while it inserts in DB it should be like  `2016-10-25 12:08:30`